# How to dynamically change variable used in an animation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I would like to dynamically change the amplitude of an animated sin wave using a slider.
I have an HTML page and CSS page with both a SVG element with a Path and a slider element. As well as a working animated sin function, however, when I try to change the variable for the amplitude with the slider, it stops working.

I am very new to Javascript and am not used to its synchronous ways. So I am lost on where the issue is occurring.

```
let xs = []

for(var i = 0; i < 200 * Math.PI; i+= .01){
    xs.push(i);
}



let t = 0;
let A = 0
let f = 3;
let height = 200;

$("#slider").on("change",function(){
    A = $(this).val();
});

function animate(){
    let points = xs.map(x => {
        let y = A * Math.sin((x + t) * f);
        return[x,y + height];
    });

    let path = "M" + points.map(p => {
        return p[0] + "," + p[1];
    }).join('L')

    document.querySelector("path").setAttribute("d", path);

    t += 1;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

};
animate();

\\the slider code looks like this in the html page: 
input type = "range" min="0" max="1000" value="0" step="1" id="slider"/>
the svg code looks like this in the css:
svg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

path {
  stroke: #2727e6;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  fill: none;
}
and like this in the html:
svg>
  path d=""></path>
/svg>
the html brackets are correct in the code, they just mess up this page so i removed them
```

Without the slider code, and a simple let A = 20 the sin wave appears, with the slider it does not. I have tried putting the slider code after the wave code, and that doesn't help, I also tried to put the wave code within the slider function and that didn't provide a result either.

I'm sure there's some issue with having two functions that both run kinda continuously and interact with each other, but I haven't used JS long enough to know what it is or how to fix it.

Comment: It might help to include the code for your SVG element as well, to demonstrate the issue. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Added the html and css for the SVG element

Comment: It [seems to work for me](https://jsfiddle.net/wnmyL1kx/), but I'm not sure the exact behavior you're expecting.

Comment: Just in case, have you included the jQuery library? Your slider code seems to require it.

Comment: I thought it was already included in the environment I was coding in, but I guess not, thanks a ton for the help!